# Running a shell script in after a contract is deployed in a private blockchain network

Tags: go-ethereum

Is there any way that i could run a shell script after a contract is deployed,since the terminal has geth Javascript console running,and there are some commands which are already in the shell script.

> ./deployContract.sh

```
command=$(echo'loadScript("./Coin.js")');
eval $command;
```

[image]

Comment: why not just open a new terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a bash syntax then it seems wrong.

You can simply just do:

```
cd scriptPath && $(command -v node) coin.js;
```